# How do I access assets included in a Rust/Cargo project installed via `cargo install`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project which includes some associated assets (Lua scripts), which I need to find at runtime.  This can mean two things:

- During development (e.g. `cargo run`), I want to find it relative to the source
- When installed via `cargo install`, the assets should be installed somewhere as well, and the installed version of the executable should find the installed assets.

I know about the option to use something like `include_str!()` to compile text files into the binary, but I don't want to do that in this case.

As far as I can tell, `cargo install` [doesn't have any support for installing anything other than the executable at the moment](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2729), which is the first problem, though I don't mind having a wrapper install script to help.

Comment: I would probably go with a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) and a couple of `include` macros; I don't think there is a better option available at the moment.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem. Looks like installing a platform specific bundle with resource files maybe the only way. I've looked at cargo-bundle but not really working for me yet.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you want it structured, you could try a mix of [`env::current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) to get the current directory, and if that doesn't find anything you can try using the executable path and load things from there. You get that with [`env::current_exe`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_exe.html).

---

I see the difficulty, which is that `cargo install` *only* copies the binary into `.cargo/bin` which means that additional resources stay in the source folder located at `.cargo/registry/src/...`.

In this case, I [agree with @ljedrz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888534/assets-included-in-a-rust-cargo-project#comment67065296_39888534) that [`include!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/macro.include.html) seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 2):

In my private project, I had to replace a "open, seek, read" by a `include_bytes!` because, as you wrote, `cargo install` doesn't handle assets. Here's an example:

**`File::open`** version

```
let mut f = File::open("examples/vertices.npy")
    .expect("Can't read file 'examples/vertices.npy'");
f.seek(SeekFrom::Start(80)).unwrap();
let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);
```

**`include_bytes!`** version

```
let vertices_bytes = include_bytes!("vertices.npy");
let mut reader = BufReader::new(&vertices_bytes[80..]);
```

I still prefer the normal reader and I'll change it when Rust supports it, but it's still a good solution while we wait.